# How to show text at a particular position on ImageView?

Tags: android, textview

So, I have got this image of a cartoon character holding a white board. To give you an idea the image is something like this.

[image]

Now, I want to show some text through textview in the centre of this white board that the character is holding in the image. The text to be shown is not too long, max 4-5 characters. Is it possible to do something like this? If so, what would be the approach to do this?

Comment: use a canvas... get the coordinates of the mickey board and draw text over it.

Comment: How can I find the coordinates of the board?

Comment: if you are using an `ImageView` your image most likely will we scaled up/down, if you want to know how it is scaled (and thus where is the top/left corner of the white board) use `ImageView#getImageMatrix()` method

Comment: I ended up doing something similar. I measured width, height and position of board with respect to the image. I then wrapped imageview in FrameLayout and then added textview to this FrameLayout dynamically setting width, height, marginLeft, marginRight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes this can be done using a FrameLayout.**

**Step 1:** First of all take this ImageView inside a Relative Layout

**Step 2:** then take a FrameLayout inside the Relative Layout.

**Step 3:** Inside this FrameLayout you can take your TextView and then you can position your TextView by giving the gravity, padding etc.

Here is the code sample for you!

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >


            /// this is your imageview
            <ImageView 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


            <FrameLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true">

           <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView 
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="Enter Your Text Here"/>

           </LinearLayout>

          </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know if this works for you !:)

Comment: This answer applies only if the board is in the centre of the image. What if the board is off centre?

Comment: no this answer applies to the whole image. you just need to position the TextView using particular width or height

Comment: How do I find this particular width or hight?

Comment: I don't see the point of wrapping the TextView in two parents i.e. FrameLayout and LinearLayout. Your technique will also work if TextView is a direct child of RelativeLayout. Actually my question in the first place was how to find the width, height and position of textview in respect of this image.

Comment: for finding the width height and position .. i have already told you to manually give the values for the same.. and then see the result.. that thing you have to do by urself

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout. This may help you.

```
<FrameLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

// this is your imageview
   <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="center" /// you can change this property according to your requirement to 'right', 'left' etc
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"  /// you can change this property according to your requirement to 'right', 'left' etc
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Enter Your Text Here"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

For proper positioning of image and text, use margin and padding accordingly.